# Pony ORM order_by json integral value

Tags: python, json, orm, ponyorm

Pony ORM appears to be sorting by the string of the Json value instead of the integral value. Is there a way to get this to order correctly?

Here's an example:

```
from pony.orm import (
    Database, Required, Optional, db_session, commit,
    show, Json)

db = Database()
db.bind('sqlite', filename=':memory:', create_db=True)

class Person(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    body = Optional(Json, default={})

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)


with db_session:
    Person(name='bort', body={'age': 1})
    Person(name='baz', body={'age': 2})
    Person(name='bar', body={'age': 10})
    Person(name='foo', body={'age': 20})

    commit()

    people = Person.select().order_by(lambda p: p.body['age'])
    show(people)
```

Output:

```
id|name|body       
--+----+-----------
1 |bort|{'age': 1} 
3 |bar |{'age': 10}
2 |baz |{'age': 2} 
4 |foo |{'age': 20}
```

Is there a way to work around this, does Pony ORM not support this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `lambda p: int(p.body['age'])`.

Comment: Did you try this? I'm pretty sure I attempted that earlier and got an error message - though not at a computer right now to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in [`0.7.3`](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/284).

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: causes Pony to raise and exception:
>   "TypeError: Function 'int' cannot be used this way: int(p.body['age'])"

Could not verify with `pony`, try if `pony` accept this:

```
def _int(v):
    return int(v)

people = Person.select().order_by(lambda p: _int(p.body['age']))
```

---

> **Question**: Is there a way to work around this, does Pony ORM not support this

You are using `sqlite`, regarding the Documentation `json` is `str`.
The Workaround:

```
lambda p: int(p.body['age'])
```

gives me **NO** Error with pure Python.

> Pony ORM: [JSON Support in Databases](https://docs.ponyorm.com/json.html)
>   For storing JSON in the database Pony uses the following types:
>
> ```
>     SQLite - TEXT
>     PostgreSQL - JSONB (binary JSON)
>     MySQL - JSON (binary JSON, although it doesn’t have ‘B’ in the name)
>     Oracle - CLOB
> ```
>
> Starting with the version 3.9 SQLite provides the JSON1 extension module. This extension improves performance when working with JSON queries, although Pony can work with JSON in SQLite even without this module.

Comment: So changing the line to `.order_by(lambda p: int(p.body['age']))` causes Pony to raise and exception: "TypeError: Function 'int' cannot be used this way: int(p.body['age'])"

Comment: It appears to behave itself when using the select statement e.g. `select(lambda p: p.body['age'] > 1)` - as in the Pony documentation. This makes me feel like it's a bug. However, I've got no confirmation through the github issues pages.

Comment: @freebie: Upddated my Answer